# Target container is not a DOM element - React and GatsbyJS - React-slick Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js, gatsby, react-slick

I am trying to use the [React-Slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) carousel component but having issues getting it to display in app and receiving this error...

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

**featuresCarousel.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Slider from 'react-slick';


class featuresCarousel extends React.Component{
  render() {
    const settings = {
      autoplay: true
    }
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>Test</div>
          <div>Test2</div>
          <div>Test3</div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <featuresCarousel />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

should display in page section **3-section.js** which is then displayed in the page.

```
import React from 'react'
import featuresCarousel from '../home/featuresCarousel'

const SectionThree = (props) => (
    <div>
        <featuresCarousel />
    </div>
)

export default SectionThree
```

Not sure if it will make a difference but I am also using [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/)GatsbyJs and my knowledge of React is limited and very new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component name featuresCarousel should be in UpperCase **FeaturesCarousel**

```
class FeaturesCarousel extends React.Component{
  render() {
    const settings = {
      autoplay: true
    }
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>Test</div>
          <div>Test2</div>
          <div>Test3</div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const SectionThree = (props) => (
    <div className="SectionThree">
        <FeaturesCarousel />
    </div>
)

export default SectionThree

ReactDOM.render(
  <SectionThree />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-omrtuu)

Comment: Cheers, that works. Better yet, I think you've taught me something. Not sure how I got so far not realising this.